# Proof by contrapositive: $x^3 + 1$ is even if and only if $x$ is uneven

Tags: logic, proof-verification

> $x^3 + 1$ with $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ is even iff $x$ is uneven.

I want to prove this using a proof by contrapositive, so this is my work:

Assume that $x$ is even, so $x = 2k$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $n^3 + 1 = 8k^3 + 1 = 2(4k^3) + 1$. Since $4k^3$ is an integer, we have proven that $x^3 + 1$ is odd if $x$ is even.

I'm pretty sure this is technically correct, but I'm worried that this proof is incomplete because of the "if and only if", I assume that means I have to prove something else to fully prove the statement.

Comment: Yes, you need a proof in the other direction as well. You've proven $x^3+1$ even $\implies$ $x$ odd (by contrapositive). You also need to prove that $x$ odd $\implies$ $x^3 +1$ even. Together they make "iff".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it is incomplete. In order to prove the other direction of the biconditional:

> ($x$ is odd) $\rightarrow$ ($x^3 + 1$ with $x\in \mathbb Z$ is even)

You need to prove its contrapositive:

> $(x^3 + 1$ with $x\in \mathbb Z$ odd) $\rightarrow$ ($x$ is even.)

Comment: $x^3 + 1$ odd > $x^3$ is even > $x$ is even. Might have to add that if $x$ is even, that $x^n$ is even, even though it is assumed trivial. Thanks

Comment: You're more than welcome. I think you've nailed it quite nicely. Yes, the product of even integers is an even integer.

Comment: I have some small questions left. I am slightly confused by the words "biconditional" and "contrapositive". The biconditional of my statement just means that a > b and b > a. Does the "if and only if" make my statement a biconditional (i.e., if it said "if", would it still be a biconditional? Also, "its contrapositive". The contrapositive of what I proved in the question (not of the biconditional), right?

Comment: Bicondition means the statement is an "iff" statement, i.e. the implication goes both directions: $\iff$. You proved one direction (one implication), but also needed to prove the other direction.  That implication is at the top of my post. The contrapositive of that implication is asserted at the bottom of the post. By proving the contrapositive, you will have proven the implication at the top of my post, thus completing the proof.

Comment: So both sides of the biconditional have a contrapositive?

Comment: Exactly. One contrapositive per implication. Two implications, therefore two contrapositives.

Answer (score 1):

You've proven that "$x^3+1$ is even $\Rightarrow x$ is odd."

You need to prove that "$x$ is odd $\Rightarrow x^3+1$ is even". To prove this, set $x=2k-1$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$. Then, 
$$x^3+1=(2k-1)^3+1=(8k^3-12k^2+6k-1)+1=2(4k^3-6k^2+3k).$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^{3} + 1 = (x + 1)\left((x + 1)^{2} - 3x \right)$.